# Xml Serializer and Deserializer with object

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

In Dot Net XmlSerializer objects to xml and Deserializer to convert xml tags to objects --
how to do in java ?

```
public static object ConvertToObject(Type objectType,String strxml)
{
  try
  {
    Object obj=null;
    XmlSerializer xs=new XmlSerializer(objectType);
    obj=xs.Deserializer(new StringReader(strxml));
    return obj;
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  }

//Xml serialized with ihuti java and converted to xml by argobj 
public static object ConvertFromObject(ihutidata argobj)//ihuti.java with xml elements
{
  try
  {
    XmlWriterSettings Sett=new XmlWritterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration=true;

    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    XmlSerializer xs=new XmlSerializer(typeof(ihutidata));
    XmlWriter xw=XmlWriter.Create(builder,settings);

    xs.Serialize(xw,argobj);
    xw.close();

    return (builder.ToString());
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    return("Exception"+e);
  }
internal string savetodb(TSring argdata,string argclientip)
{
  ihutidata req=(ihutidata)DataProcessing.ConvertToObject(typeof(ihutidata),argdata);

  if(req!=null)
  {
    ......
    ......
  }
}
```

ya I agree with XStream it convert the xml to object and vice versa but my problem is....
i have to call converttoobject() with class and pass it as object.
As the program remains in C# i am doing same process in java.

ihutidata is an class which contains xml Root elements, attributes and elements etc.
Is it Possible in Java ?

Comment: looks like I don't understand what you need to do. ConvertToObject - is what xstream.fromXML does; ConvertFromObject looks like xstream.toXML; "i have to call both by refering one" - what do you mean?

Comment: you know at last i have to call like this Ex : ihutidata req=(inhutidata)DataProcessing.ConvertToObject(typeof(ihutidata),argdata);//ihutidata is an class which contains xmlelements and attributes to be accessed in the same package.

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries to do this job (serialize and deserialize objects), one of the simplest in use is [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) is example of using:

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

Now you can simple run `String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);` and the result is:

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</person>
```

To get object back run `Person newJoe = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml);`

Another possible option could be [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding):

> Java Architecture for XML Binding
>   (JAXB) allows Java developers to map
>   Java classes to XML representations.
>   JAXB provides two main features: the
>   ability to marshal Java objects into
>   XML and the inverse, i.e. to unmarshal
>   XML back into Java objects. In other
>   words, JAXB allows storing and
>   retrieving data in memory in any XML
>   format, without the need to implement
>   a specific set of XML loading and
>   saving routines for the program's
>   class structure. It is similar to
>   xsd.exe and xmlserializers in .Net
>   Framework.

But as for me, most tasks can be done with XStream, which lightweight and more easy (imho)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: It serializes an object to XML and deserializes an XML back to an object.

Answer (score 0):

In Java there's [`XMLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html)

Your methods will look something like:

```
public static <T> T convertToObject(Class<T> objectType, String xml) {
    XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(new ReaderInputStream(new StringReader(xml)));
    T result = (T) decoder.readObject();
    decoder.close();
    return result;
}

public static String convertToString(Object object) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new WriterOutputStream(sw));
    encoder.writeObject(object);
    encoder.close();
    return sw.toString();
}
```

(Note that `ReaderOutputStream` is from apache commons-io)

Comment: i can't use xml encoder or decoder for objecttype as argument

Comment: becoz it doesn't accepts the Typeof() and Type datatypes while passed from other functions.

Comment: @RSR I didn't understand that comment. What is Typeof? And what is "Type datatypes"

Comment: i had displayed full code above which u refer and see that typeof() used to refer class which contains xmlelement attributes while serializing and Type used to access class object

Comment: I had followed your code for xmlencoder but exception arise and doesn't it moves to other functions                                      java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized opening tag: soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ihut="http://www.hutiamdps.com/IHutiGprsModem" 
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized opening tag: soap:Header 
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized closing tag: autoip
Continuing ...
String File :SaveToDB Exception :java.util.NoSuchElementException
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @RSR I guess you are using your own xml format and try to deserialize from it - it is not possible with the XMLDecoder. It has to use the format used by XMLEncoder

Comment: please tell me how to call the function u had specified

Comment: you have to first use convertToXml, and the use the generated XML in convertToObject

Comment: ya i know that but the input i am receiving is Soap+Xml tags with data i am getting the input and converting it to String it means whole part of data remains same with xml tags but extension will be string. so that i can pass it to other function easily.

Comment: @RSR in that case look at JAX-WS and JAXB